# MySQL Connection Error on heavy load with wordpress site

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, high-traffic

I've used WordPress site, If we give multiple requests using JMeter or on search engine boot time MySQL server getting down

I have changed the below configuration on my server

- key_buffer = 25M
- max_allowed_packet = 1M
- thread_stack = 128K
- table_cache = 25
- innodb_buffer_pool_size= "64M" to "512M"
- max_connections = 200;

How to fix the issue?

This issue happens only on high traffic like 200 to 500 request at a time

Comment: You have tagged mysql error for "Syntax error", if that's really the case, then please include the details. If that's not the case, what exactly is "getting down"

Comment: My MySQL server is shut-down automatically when the apache getting a high load.

I don't know exactly this issue form apache server or MySQL server or from my server hardware.

Comment: Now I have increased the server RAM size 4GB to 16BG, It is working fine. But I don't think this is a correct solution.